# c# How to insert textbox value and save it to sql database?

Tags: c#, .net, database, visual-studio-2005, insert-update

How to insert textbox value and save it to sql database?
I need some help here regarding to the question above. When I clicked button save, it should update the input textbox to the sql database Workers. Could you guys make some coding sample to achieve this? Because what I do is not working at all. This is the coding :

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
#region SaveButton
            // System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ();

            //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb;
            //cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder (da);

            //add to Dataset a new row
            DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Workers"].NewRow();

            //add data to the new row just have been created
            //refer to first_Name
            dRow[1] = textBox1.Text;
            dRow[2] = textBox2.Text;
            dRow[3] = textBox3.Text;

            //add command
            //add to table worker a new row that declared by row variable name dRow
            ds1.Tables["Workers"].Rows.Add(dRow);

            MaxRows = MaxRows + 1; //to enable last row is still last row
            inc = MaxRows - 1;

            //call data adapter da to update and save data into database sql server
            //da.Update(ds1, "Workers");

            MessageBox.Show("Entry Added!");
#endregion
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename =D:\\MyWorkers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";


            string strSQL = "INSERT INTO Workers (first_Name, last_Name, job_Title )" + " VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', " + " '" + textBox3.Text + "') ";





            con.Close();  
        }
```

Comment: You are doing nothing. No wonder, it isn't working ;-)

Comment: ...and this is how sql-injection attacks start.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this question by connecting properly to the Workers database. YeaY!!

Here's the right code for this question:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region SaveButton
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;
    string sql = "SELECT * From tblWorkers";
    da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb;
    cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder (da);

    //add to Dataset a new row
    DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Workers"].NewRow();

    //add data to the new row that has just been created
    //refer to first_Name
    dRow[1] = textBox1.Text;
    dRow[2] = textBox2.Text;
    dRow[3] = textBox3.Text;

    //add command
    //add to table worker a new row that declared by row variable name dRow
    ds1.Tables["Workers"].Rows.Add(dRow);

    MaxRows = MaxRows + 1; //to enable last row is still last row
    inc = MaxRows - 1;

    //call data adapter da to update and save data into database sql server
    da.Update(ds1, "Workers");              

    MessageBox.Show("Entry Added!");
    con.Close();
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to Execute non query

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx#Y506)

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

Comment: Button save should have to save it to database, update it permanently. Any suggestion on how to do this since using insert is not working?

Comment: da.Update(ds1, "Workers");<<---Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @justinlabenne Any suggestion on how to use sql command for this button?

Comment: Well for starters, you'll want to decide whether you want to use the dataadapter or just write your sql yourself.